# how can I find the default gateway of an ubuntu box

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ip

how can I find the default gateway of an ubuntu box

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Classic answer

```
route
```

Look for a line that says something like:

```
default         10.63.3.254     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

The second column contains the default gateway, and the last column is the interface.

You can also use the ip command:

```
ip route
```

which will give you something like

```
default via 10.63.3.254 dev eth0
```

Comment: Note that the `ip route` is the currently preferred way of extracting such information. The old route command is kept for compatibility. Also, you can see the IPv6 default route using `ip -6 route`.

Comment: you are correct... but I'm a sucker for old school commands ;)

Comment: for ipv6 use ip -6 route

Answer (score 3):

You can also use "netstat -*n*r" (I usually leave the n in the flags, so as to not have to wait for host resolution if there's a DNS issue).

Answer (score 2):

```
grog:/var/log# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

You can also check /etc/network/interfaces to see what it'll be on next reboot or networking restart.